# Play sound on widget click

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, widget

Here's my code, it opens the main activity, but I can't seem to find a way to just make the widget play a sound.

I tried to:

- add a button to the widget (didn't work)
- add an `OnClickListener` to the main activity (which works but it opens the main activity and I just want the sound not the activity)
- write a new method to play the sound with the `MediaPlayer` `sound.start()` method in it and calling it (didn't work)

I've looked in the android dev page and all I was able to find was how to use the `MediaPlayer`, but it says nothing about playing audio from a widget.

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;



public class ClockWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.clock_widget_layout);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.AnalogClock0, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do it you need to use a `service` which you call like this

```
Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
startService(svc);

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.trck);
       //configure other settings    
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

 }
```

Please register this service in `Manifest`.

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService" />
```

and you could do smth like this in widget

```
public class ClockWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private final String ACTION_WIDGET_PLAY = "PlaySong";
    private final String ACTION_WIDGET_PAUSE = "PauseSong";
    private final String ACTION_WIDGET_STOP = "StopSong";   
    private final int INTENT_FLAGS = 0;
    private final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews controlButtons = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.main);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);

        Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);

        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);


        PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                this, REQUEST_CODE, playIntent, INTENT_FLAGS);
        PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                this, REQUEST_CODE, pauseIntent, INTENT_FLAGS);
        PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                this, REQUEST_CODE, stopIntent, INTENT_FLAGS);

        controlButtons.setOnClickPendingIntent(
                R.id.btnPlay, playPendingIntent);
        controlButtons.setOnClickPendingIntent(
                R.id.btnPause, pausePendingIntent);
        controlButtons.setOnClickPendingIntent(
                R.id.btnStop, stopPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, controlButtons);         
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I call the service?

Comment: whenever you need to start listening for the action (play for example). You need to start the service before the user taps "Play" so the service can receive the pending intent.

Comment: If I start the service in MainActivity, the sound starts playing automatically :(

Comment: here in  the intent you can have a custom REQUEST_CODE for start (PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                this, REQUEST_CODE, playIntent, INTENT_FLAGS);) 

and then have a condition in onStartCommand to check for that specific  REQUEST_CODE

Comment: I've created a new question with my detailed case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67304255/make-an-android-widget-that-plays-a-certain-sound-on-click