# Easiest way to make a widget do the same thing as a button that is already in-app?

Tags: android, android-studio, button, widget

I have an app that contains a button that plays short sound when clicked. I'd like to basically make a widget that will do the same thing from homescreen.

What's the easiest way to make such a widget?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try to make a widget yet?

Answer (score 0):

This [Building app widgets](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/content/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-2-app-widgets/2-1-p-app-widgets/2-1-p-app-widgets.html) seems to provide some pretty good instructions in order to make your widget.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Play sound on widget click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216333/play-sound-on-widget-click) answers your question.

Widgets themselves don't have any API that will let you play sounds however running a service in your app and triggering the service calls on click events in your widget should work.